# C++ WINAPI, CALLBACK, INT

Tags: c++, winapi

Раньше не особо обращал внимание, но что значат и зачем нужны слова (не знаю как называть) в методах в winapi приложении?

В чем разница между INT и int?

Что здесь

```
int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
```

значит WINAPI?

что здесь значит

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
```

CALLBACK?

Я  примерно понимаю, что CALLBACK ето метод обратного вызова, WINAPI наверное указывает на то что етот main WINAPI приложения а INT ето int..

Но как на самом деле?)

Буду рад примерам кода с использованием етих и других директив ну или документация, еще что небудь)

Comment: Для начала можно было бы самому поглядеть, как определены эти символы.

Answer (score 2):

1. Разницы никакой. `INT` это просто псевдоним ([alias](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/typedef)) определенный в одном из заголовочных файлов WinApi(`WinDef.h`).
2. `WINAPI`, `CALLBACK` (существуют и прочие) - это макросы определенные в одном из заголовочных файлов WinApi(`WinDef.h`). Их значение зависит от настроек компиляции и других факторов.

`WINAPI`, `CALLBACK` определяют [соглашение о вызове функции](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5). Довольно часто `CALLBACK` является `__stdcall`.

**Но**, стандарты языков C и C++ не определяют такие сущности, как протоколы вызовов функций. Эти понятия зависят от операционной системы, компилятора, линковщика.